# Google Play Services : target=android-19 in project.properties

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am utilizing the library BaseGameUtils and google-play-services_lib. In the project.properties file I could see the below mentioned line .

```
target=android-19.
```

What is the significance of this? Can I change this to "target=android-21". This is just to be in sync with the App's manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can change this, Depending target only, packages load for you in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

What is the significance of target=android-19?

target = android-**X** in project properties file means that Eclipse will not allow use methods or classes from SDK higher than **X**. It will show compiler errors.

How to change target:

- Right click your project.
- Then click "Properties".
- Then select "Android" from the tree on the left.
- You can then select the target version on the right.

**NOTE**: Before doing this make sure your project.properties and classpath are not in read-only mode otherwise it won't work. Also don't try to edit this file manually.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule I use the following guidelines

android:minSdkVersion="8"

Set this to the minimum level you want to support. Check which Android version that it actually relates to and make sure that you have compatibility with that version.  For example, I think 8 = Android 2.2, which could be a problem if you are using google play services libraries.  It is good practice to at least test that you app will work properly on this version using the emulator, because otherwise you will get a lot of errors and bad reviews.

android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

I usually set this to the maximum version that I have actually tested my app on.  I thin 21 is Android 4.4, so you should be making sure that your app works correctly on this version of Android.  At the least, you should test that it will run in an emulator that is configured with this version of Android.

Hope this helps.